# Styling datetime symfony / bootstrap

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, datetime

I am using Symfony and Bootstrap for a personnal project.

I created a form with a field "datetime". Twig generates me several inputs (day, month, year, hour, minute) but it's not really "user friendly".

I would like to know how I can styling the input to create a datetimepicker, like the one here : http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Here some code :
 - FormType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('dateStart');
        $builder->add('dateEnd');
    }
```

- Twig :

  ```
  {{ form_widget(form.dateStart)}}
  {{ form_errors(form.dateStart) }}

  {{ form_widget(form.dateEnd)}}
  {{ form_errors(form.dateEnd) }}
  ```

How could I do that ?

Thanks for you answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set field [widget](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#widget) as "single_text" and [html5](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#html5) option to false:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('dateStart', 'datetime', array(
        'widget' => 'single_text', 
        'html5' => false,
    ));
   //...
}
```

On twig template:

```
<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
    {{ form_widget(form.dateStart, {attr: { 
        'data-format': "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" },
    }) }}
    <span class="add-on"> 
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

When setting html5 option to false it avoid native calendar HTML 5 to be used, in other words it'll cause a input type="text" rather input tipe="datetime".
From Symfony [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#html5):

*If this is set to true (the default), it'll use the HTML5 type (date, time or datetime) to render the field. When set to false, it'll use the text type.
**This is useful when you want to use a custom JavaScript datapicker, which often requires a text type instead of an HTML5 type.***

Comment: Ok, now I have 5 input text :) but no datetime picker :-/

Comment: @carndacier, sorry, it was a typo. I've changed my post

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's answer half my problem, but I'll try someting to customize it. Just a question : why do you put "html5" to false ?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll try it later. If it works, I'll valid your answer ;)